# Is there a more elegant way to instantiate this Map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a very simple question that I just couldn't find a way to properly phrase to get some answer on Google. I simply have a key value map to simplify some recurring data but I can't help but feel I am doing things a brute-force and improper way.

Simple example:

```
$scope.techMap = [];
$scope.techMap["HTML 5"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp";
$scope.techMap["CSS 3"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/css3/";
//...
```

Is there some better way of doing this or am I going about it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.techMap = {
    "HTML 5": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp",
    "CSS 3":  "http://www.w3schools.com/css3/",
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.techMap = {
    'HTML 5': "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp",
    'CSS 3': "http://www.w3schools.com/css3/"
};
```

BTW, please [don't use w3schools for anything](http://w3fools.com). Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I actually was under the impression they were connected with the W3C - which is why I thought it made sense to use their material.

Comment: @Alex - That is the main problem with that site. It appears that they are affiliated with the W3C, when in fact they clearly aren't.